# How do I get OpenId Connect access token and refresh tokens in ASP.NET MVC 5?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, openid-connect

I am using the Microsoft.Security.Owin.OpenIdConnect to implement Single Sign-On in my ASP.NET MVC 5 app. This is the code I am using:

```
app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions {
                ClientId = "id",
                ClientSecret = "secret",
                MetadataAddress = "https://accounts.google.com/.well-known/openid-configuration",
                RedirectUri = "http://localhost:****",
                ResponseType = "code id_token",
                Scope = "openid email profile",
                SignInAsAuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie
            });
```

However, I want to get the access token, and if necessary the refresh token, to use for API codes. There is very little documentation for how to do this. Apparently I need to use `AcquireTokenByAuthorizationCode`, but I can only find this function in an ActiveDirectory assembly, which doesn't seem like it is something that would be used for OpenId. How do I set the options so I can get the access token to use in APIs?

Answer (score 1):

In your ResponseType, put token as well